# Spark installation for production, pip install or not?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pip

I would like to install Pyspark 2.4.4. I have seen that I can download the Spark package or use pip install. I only need Pyspark, are they the same with both installations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do `python pip install pyspark` but it doesn't come with Hadoop binaries which is necessary for the spark to function properly.

The easiest way to install is by using `python findspark`

download .tgz file from the spark [website](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) which comes with Hadoop binaries

```
pip install findspark
```

In Python:

```py
import findspark

finspark.init('\path\to\extracted\binaries\folder')

import pyspark
```